# No Mime-Type for .jsp after updating url-pattern in JSF

Tags: jsp, jsf, mime-types, url-pattern

i am using JSF (2.2) with mojarra 2.2.9 and i get the following issues:

(its german, i will translate it later):

```
Für Datei xyz.jsp konnte kein Mime-Typ gefunden werden.
```

It means something like: "There is no Mime-Type for xyz.jsp"

This happened after i set my url-pattern in the web.xml from:

```
<url-pattern>faces/*</url-pattern>
```

to

```
<url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
```

This is my current web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee     http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>Bewerbungsportal</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.pdf</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.jspx</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

As you can see, i tried to add .jsp, .jsf and so on. But it does not help.

If i am adding:

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>jsp</extension>
    <mime-type>application/xml</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

The hint mentioned above seems to be solved, but a nother hint is still active:

```
Navigations-Fall wurde für Komponente j_idt125 nicht aufgelöst
```

it is german and means: "The navigationrule for component j_idt125 cant be solved"

If i set the url-pattern to the default, everything is fine, but i have to use the url-pattern:     *.xhtml

Comment: This question is confusing. Get rid of all other URL patterns and stick to `*.xhtml` (you're absolutely not supposed to map `FacesServlet` on `*.jsp`). Reframe the question accordingly. As to the problem, are you using JSP or Facelets as view technology?